# phpMyAdmin current user cannot drop views. How do I grant it the correct privileges?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

The hosting server recently got replaced due to crash and I now have a issue when trying to drop any database view in phpMyadmin I get the following:

> #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SYSTEM_USER privilege(s) for this operation

I created a DB user and gave it all privileges and tried with PHP and same issue.

I can drop tables but not drop views. I have WHM access and CPanel access.

`SHOW GRANTS` for phpMyAdmin shows the following:

[image]

phpMyAdmin version 5.2.1
I do not have SSH access.

Is there something I can do to allow me to drop a view? Since I cannot change view details in phpMyAdmin without dropping and creating the view from scratch.

Or is it a setting my webhost must fix? What setting should I ask them to fix?

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered that when I create my own view I can drop the view without issues.

The hosting provider loaded a backup of the database, and it seems that it is done with a different user and then prevents other users from deleting the views. I haven't tested if the same is true for tables.

Once the hosting provider deleted the view I could recreate and delete that same view without issue.